# xcode / cocoa: Reuse identifiers in custom cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview with custom cells via a uitableviewcell subclass. The cells have a label lblResult that changes after a a result is received. It works well, but, when I then scroll down my tableview, other random cells now have that same result label (but they still have their proper "name" label).

I figure this has to do with reuse identifiers, but I'm not sure.

Let me know if you need any more code to understand my problem.

The cell is made like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";
FriendCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[FriendCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:nil];
}
```

Then before being returned, cell is passed into a loadingQueue dictionary.
When the result loads there is a resultComplete method which loads the cell from the loadingQueue dictionary and the following is called:

```
   [[cell lblNumTagged] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)",[thisDictionary count]]];
    [[cell lblNumTagged] setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is because cells are being re-used.

In your custom cell class you can use the [prepareForReuse](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) delegate method, which is being called before the cell is being reused and clear the cell's label there...

Comment: Right. But, now when I scroll down the new ones are cleared but when I scroll back up the original one is cleared too, but I want the result to stay there.

Comment: If you are doing custom drawing, you need to call [cell setNeedsDisplay] before returning the cell, to force a draw update.

Comment: I tried that. But my original cell is still being reset. Here's what I think is happening tell me if this makes sense: View opens --> cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for cells in the view, as you scroll down, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called again and the new cells are formatted but use the previously created cells so as not to make 1000 objects --> when I scroll back up, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called again and my previously edited cell is reset. As a solution, should I implement a "state" function in my data source that tells cellForRowAtIndexPath what exactly it should be drawing?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just in case.  I think it is because when you create a new cell you are NOT specifying the identifier.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";
FriendCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
   cell = [[FriendCell alloc]
         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Try it like this, note the end of the last line.....